# How to reduce mlkit-ink-recognition android app size

Tags: android, google-mlkit

I have included mlkit-ink-recognition in my android app by including this dependency following from [this official doc](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/digital-ink-recognition/android):

```
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:digital-ink-recognition:18.1.0'
```

Though the [model installation path official doc](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/tips/installation-paths) about this dependency states it uses dynamically downloaded model, still after adding this dependency, my app's size got increased by about 45MB. Does this dependency includes some base model bundled which is causing this size increase or the library itself without any model could have such a large size (which looks incorrect)? Any suggestion how to reduce the app size with this dependency (provided the unbundled model installation is not applicable with this library as per official docs)?

apk size without ink:
[image]

apk sizes (debug and release) with ink:
[image]

[image]

Comment: 45MB doesn't seem right. Could you try some general best practice about how to reduce Android apk size? https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size

Comment: It's happening. On adding this lib, my ~9MB app is becoming ~55MB app. https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size these changes are already applied.

Comment: I built the ML Kit digital ink demo app. Even with native libraries for all 4 architectures, the total apk size is just 16MB.

Comment: @Steven, it's strange, apk size is increasing about ~45MB by just adding the mentioned dependency to project (added snaps of the apks built at my end).